# Is the following code threadsafe?

Tags: java, concurrency

I see the following example in Java Concurrency in Practice book, and it is mentioned that the class is threadsafe, and there is no information given about Person class. If the person class is mutable, then after adding a Person Object, it can be modified, say value that is used in equals method may be modified by another thread, in that case the following code will not be threadsafe. Is that correct statement?

```
@ThreadSafe
public class PersonSet {
@GuardedBy("this")
private final Set<Person> mySet = new HashSet<Person>();

public synchronized void addPerson(Person p) {
    mySet.add(p);
}

public synchronized boolean containsPerson(Person p) {
    return mySet.contains(p);
}
```

}

Comment: If they are creating a `Set<Person>` in *Java: Concurrency in Practice* book, you can assume that the `Person` class is immutable..

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is thread safe. Thread safe in the sense that only one thread at a time can do read on set via `containsPerson` method or may be able to add set via `addPerson` method.

This class is thread safe because it has one Object state i.e. Set it self. So it protects it's state by allowing only one thread to work upon it.

However it doesn't guarantee that Person can't be modified by multiple thread. If you want to achieve the same you can either create Person as immutable object or you make it thread safe as well i.e. allow only one thread to modify it's state.

Answer (score 3):

Your statement is correct: if the `Person` class is mutable, and an update is done on a field that contributes to `hashCode` and `equals`, then the `PersonSet` will have a problem - no matter in which thread.

The *no duplicate* `Set` contract will be broken, silently...

Answer (score 0):

here object lock(this) is being used . the object which was used to access methods of personSet class which is of personSet type ,No two threads can access any of methods  of personSet at one time. In locking there is no dependency of Person class. So personSet class is thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

The thread safety in question here only pertains to the set, not the *contents* of the set.  There are no allowances or checks made on a retrieval (i.e. `get`) operation on the set, so that portion is thread unsafe.  Since that's not exposed, then the operations of adding and checking to see if an element is contained in the set are indeed thread-safe.

Note that while these operations are indeed safe for threads, they're also not concurrent.  Since `synchronized` will block multiple threads from interacting with the method at once, these methods will become a bottleneck if used in a highly concurrent environment.